# Displaying the To address prefilled in Email Intent?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, extra

[image]I am not able to pre fill the TO field in Email client to the "to" address mentioned in the extras here:

```
EmailImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);   
                it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "toaddress@gmail.com");   
                it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Regarding Policy Info");  
                it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "When is my next Premium due");  
                //it.setType("text/plain");   
                it.setType("message/rfc822");  
                startActivity(it);   
            }  
        });
```

What is the problem?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: would you mind posting your working solution? (I'm facing the same issue, but I do have put the address in an array already...still empty "TO field")

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to put the address in an array:

```
it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"toaddress@gmail.com"});
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL).

Comment: what did it take to work now for you? (assuming that u provided a string array for recipient before?). maybe u can post the final working sample code!? thx.

Comment: @vaiomike  Didn't understand the question.

Comment: My question was targeted @sneha, whether he could post his working solution. (I have the same problem, although I put the address in an array)

Comment: @vaiomike - so post the comment under his question, so he will be notified.

Comment: sry, my bad. thought he's notified since he has accepted this as the solution.

Answer (score 7):

I've got something like this and its works:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("plain/text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "some@email.address" });
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mail body");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: experiencing the same problems (using your exact same code above); TO filed just remains empty :-(

Answer (score 2):

When using ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE,

You have to provide an array of String for Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL Binyamin Sharet shown you.

If the requirement is to provide only one Address then use Intent.ACTION_SEND.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"","your email"});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "someone@gmail.com" });
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, edt_msg.getText().toString());
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, edt_subjct.getText().toString());
                        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file_img_capt);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                        startActivity(emailIntent);
```